# How can I show a caption, subcaption and source similar to this NY Times style?

Tags: floats, knitr

I would like to create a LaTeX document that mimics the style used on the NY Times' Upshot Blog (example at [NY Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/12/16/upshot/why-even-a-good-midterm-turnout-for-democrats-in-north-carolina-fell-short.html)).

Here is the desired output:

---

[image: Desired output]

---

They have these features:

- A thin gray line at the start of the figure
- A large title
- A smaller description below the title
- The chart
- A footnote sized "source" text below the chart
- A closing thin gray line

---

This is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Helps the layout (put tables (H)ere!)
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{ruled}
\restylefloat{figure}

\begin{document}

\section{Chart Example}

This is some text above the chart.

<<fig.cap="Chart showing Cars Data", fig.pos="H", echo=FALSE, message=FALSE>>=
plot(cars)
@

And here is some text below the chart.

\end{document}
```

---

### [image]